# Open a file according to its name

Tags: macos, pdf, launch-services

On my iMac I would like to open PDF files with Preview, while PDF files that have 'docuni' in the name (e.g. 'docuni1.pdf' or 'docuni2.pdf' etc.) I would like to open by default with Adobe Reader. Is this customisation possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Smart Folder (essentially a Spotlight search) that contains the files with the names you want, wherever they are located. You can then select them all in one go, and set the "Open With..." app in Get Info.

If you use Command Alt I, that will give you one Get Info window for all selected files.

So, in short: there's no automatic way to 'teach' macOS.